# How do customize excel with using datatable in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, datatables, export-to-excel

I m using DataTable (Jquery) to export excel file. But I facing on how do put extra information to export excel file. I have tried some code but it didn't meet my expectation.

My expected exported excel file is as below picture:

[image]

---

However my output is as below picture, my title report and address is located at middle isn't on top of report:

[image]

---

with using code below:

```
{
    extend: 'excelHtml5',
    title: 'Trace Report',
    messageTop: 'ABC company' + 'address',
    //message: "Any message for header inside the file. I am not able to put message in next row in excel file but you can use \n"+'modelID'+modelId，
    render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
        return '<a href="' + data + '">Download</a>'; //change the button text here
    },
    customize: function (xlsx) {

        var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
        var numrows = 10;

        // add styles for the column header, these row will be moved down
        var clRow = $('row', sheet);

        //$(clRow[0]).find('c').attr('s', 32);

        //update Row
        clRow.each(function () {
            var attr = $(this).attr('r');

            var ind = parseInt(attr);
            ind = ind + numrows;
            //ind is num of row +1
            $(this).attr("r", ind);
        });

        // Create row before data
        $('row c ', sheet).each(function (index) {
            var attr = $(this).attr('r');

            var pre = attr.substring(0, 1);
            //pre=A,B,C..-F repeat 5 time
            var ind = parseInt(attr.substring(1, attr.length));
            ind = ind + numrows;
            $(this).attr("r", pre + ind);
        });

        function addRow(index, data) {
            var row = sheet.createElement('row');

            row.setAttribute("r", index);
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var key = data[i].k;
                var value = data[i].v;

                var c = sheet.createElement('c');
                c.setAttribute("t", "inlineStr");
                c.setAttribute("s", "2"); /*set specific cell style here*/
                c.setAttribute("r", key + index);

                var is = sheet.createElement('is');
                var t = sheet.createElement('t');
                var text = sheet.createTextNode(value)


                t.appendChild(text);
                is.appendChild(t);
                c.appendChild(is);

                row.appendChild(c);

                debugger;
            }

            return row;
        }

        //add data to extra rows
        var countryStateList = 'asd';
        var agencyValue = 'asd';
        var reportGroupList = 'asd';
        var certNo = '3e'

        var r1 = addRow(1, [{
            k: 'A',
            v: 'Certificate Number'
        }, {
            k: 'B',
            v: 'Model ID:'
        }, {
            k: 'C',
            v: 'Serial Number'
        }, {
            k: 'D',
            v: 'Calibration Date'
        }]);
        var r2 = addRow(2, [{
            k: 'A',
            v: countryStateList
        }, {
            k: 'B',
            v: agencyValue
        }, {
            k: 'C',
            v: reportGroupList
        }, {
            k: 'D',
            v: certNo
        }]); //add one cell for row 1 
        //$('row c[r^="A"]', sheet).attr( 's', '25' );
        var sheetData = sheet.getElementsByTagName('sheetData')[0];
        // sheetData.insertBefore(r4,sheetData.childNodes[0]);
        // sheetData.insertBefore(r3,sheetData.childNodes[0]);
        sheetData.insertBefore(r2, sheetData.childNodes[0]);

        sheetData.insertBefore(r1, sheetData.childNodes[0]);
    }
}
```